# Field 'name' on type 'RemoteDependencyData' is too long

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-application-insights

I've just added Application Insights to my React application. When it attempts to contact the Application Insights server to notify it about Google Adverts loading, I get a 400 error which says: "Field 'name' on type 'RemoteDependencyData' is too long"

I've looked through the config for ApplicationInsights and don't find a way to shorten the name or to ignore certain fetches.

Here is my configuration of the plugin:

```
  initialize(reactPluginConfig) {
    const instrumentationKey = publicRuntimeConfig.AppInsights.InstrumentKey

    this.appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
      config: {
        instrumentationKey,
        maxBatchInterval: 0,
        disableFetchTracking: false,
        extensions: [this.reactPlugin],
        extensionConfig: {
          [this.reactPlugin.identifier]: reactPluginConfig
        }
      }
    })
    this.appInsights.loadAppInsights()
  }
```

Here's the kind of value I'm seeing being passed:

```
name: "GET https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?gdfp_req=1&pvsid=3899864230170460&correlator=1176166438184394&output=json_html&callback=googletag.impl.pubads.callbackProxy3&impl=fifs&adsid=AGt39rSWeAHAYcWHd55Pv2v0Hn4qiAL6Sl5QTuM8A7Vy0061-z2dWmbQdMXwo-8N5G4e1e5VaGTTm0lLSoER&jar=2019-6-18-23&json_a=1&eid=21063203%2C21063317%2C22316438&vrg=2019061301&guci=2.2.0.0.2.2.0.0&plat=1%3A32776%2C2%3A32776%2C8%3A32776&sc=0&sfv=1-0-33&ecs=20190618&iu_parts=12671339%2Caa_sbdept_bottom_728x90&enc_prev_ius=0%2F1&prev_iu_szs=728x90&prev_scp=department%3Dbody-armor%26category%3DBody%2520Armor%2520%2526%2520Protection&cookie_enabled=1&bc=31&abxe=1&lmt=1560900694&dt=1560900694440&dlt=1560900618064&idt=11742&frm=20&biw=2543&bih=400&oid=3&adxs=1244&adys=2379&adks=1434505235&ucis=d&ifi=9&u_tz=-420&u_his=4&u_h=1440&u_w=2560&u_ah=1440&u_aw=2560&u_cd=24&u_nplug=3&u_nmime=4&u_sd=1&flash=0&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fdepartment%2F10A56330.aspx&dssz=15&icsg=48955391&std=20&vis=2&dmc=8&scr_x=0&scr_y=0&psz=728x90&msz=728x90&blev=0.98&bisch=1&ga_vid=1753854358.1560900630&ga_sid=1560900630&ga_hid=551901891&fws=0"
```

Comment: Can you please point to a package of Application Insights you used?

Comment: "@microsoft/applicationinsights-react-js": "^2.0.2",
    "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web": "^2.0.1",

Comment: I'd recommend to create a github issue in this repository: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/tree/master/vNext/extensions/applicationinsights-react-js.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this telemetry initializer below your call to loadAppInsights to modify your telemetry items on the fly. In this case, it will truncate the RemoteDependencyData name field.

```
appInsights.addTelemetryInitializer(item => {
  if (item.baseType === 'RemoteDependencyData') {
    if (item.baseData.name.length > 1024) {
      item.baseData.name = item.baseData.name.substr(0, 1024);
    }
  }
});
```